# undefined_methodError on less css code in phonegap application running on 2.2 android

Tags: android, css, cordova, less

I spend quite some time everyday on stackoverflow. This place is really great!

But this is my very first question, so every advice about it is very welcome :)

I'm working on a mobile app using phonegap. I use less css and it works fine on my nexus 5, but I have an error related to less on my old htc desire under android 2.2 :

> undefined_methodError: Object function(a,b){return b instanceof
>   Array?a=this.flatten(b,a):a.push(b),a} has no method 'bind'
>
> in index.less on line null, column 0:
>
> 1 // Constants

The last line is the first line in my index.css file.

I've been looking on google and here for two days and I don't find anything.

Here is my index.html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="app/index.less" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/async.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/handlebars.js"></script>
        <script>
            less = {
                log_level: 1
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/less-1.5.0.min.js"></script>
        <title>Kwali.to</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to "compile" the less code on the client because I have many sizes that are dependent to the screen resolution.

I really have no idea how to solve this and I hope it's not just a matter of incompatibility with my too old android...

How to solve this? What can I do to make my code work? Any help will be appreciated :)

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "[Less Browser Support](http://lesscss.org/usage/#browser-support)". I.e. Less requires an ES-5 compatible JavaScript environment to run in. You can use [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) polyfill which will add the JavaScript features that Less requires.

Comment: The error doesn't appear anymore, but the page isn't rendered as expected. I guess that it cannot work perfectly on those old browsers and I have to find another solution to embed a "compiled" CSS in the application. Thanks!

Comment: It actually works! It was my css that was incompatible with that browser version, so keeping on loading the less file and compile it live works!!! Thanks a bunch!