# problems with bootstrap's less.min.js and ie8

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, less

I'm trying to make wordpress theme and everything was going well until I didn't test my site in ie8.

I use bootstrap 3 and less files.

When I check my site in ie8, I get this error: "Object doesnt support this property or method" and my site is broken.

Here is my code in head of my site:

```
 <!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="no-js ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>

   <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">

    <title><?php wp_title('|',true,'right'); ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Meta -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />



 <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/x-less" href="
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . "/less/bootstrap.less"; ?>" />


<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />


 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/less.min.js'; ?>" /></script>

 <!-- HTML5 shim for IE backwards compatibility -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/polyfill.js">
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/es5-shim.js">
      </script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/respond.js">
       </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
   <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21069759/2712740

Comment: check if jquery loaded twice, because you are loading jquery from google cdn, wordpress also will load jquery from its wp-include directory.

Comment: thank you for advice, but I have already fixed it. I converted bootstrap's less to css and now it's working... Best regards